# max_execution_time vs set_time_limit approach in php

Tags: php

Am trying to increase script execution time for a curl request in php for uploading a very large files.

I Can set the curl timeout as follows

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
```

Now I need to ensure that php script does not timeout as well. 
Am confused on the approached to be implemented irrespective of 
whether the server is running **Apache or Nginx or IIS** etc.

Some articles suggest that `max_execution_time` is good since it uses `ini_set()` and that you can gets its results using `init_get()`
while some scholars suggest the use `set_time_limit` saying that `max_execution_time` is only to be used when running apache.

Am really confused as my coconut head keeps cracking. Any suggestions on the best way to go will be appreciated

1.) Am I to use **max_execution_time** or **set_time_limit** or should I use both

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 5 miutes
set_time_limit(300);
```

2.)Again In which scenario is **max_execution_time** preferable over **set_time_limit** and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that my hosting company set their default timeout for sending each request so  no matter how one tends to increase
the max_execution timeout, its still ineffective.

I now realize that the best option is to use

`set_time_limit(28)` within the main while loop so each loop iteration of chunked file is limited to `28 seconds` as opposed to setting it to the whole script.

something like this is what I did

```
while(){
set_time_limit(28);
//process your chunked data here on each loop


}
```